# using mysqli_result->free() gives Undefined variable and Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code-

```
$link = @new mysqli(_HOST, _USER, _PASS, _DB);
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM CHAT_USERS;");
if ($result->num_rows <= 0){
    echo "None Found.";
}
else
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $strUsers .= $row['USERNAME']. ",";
        $roomCount += 1;
    }
    $strUsers = $roomCount.",".$strUsers;
}

// Close connection
$mysqli_result->free();    //line 37
$link->close();
```

What I'm getting -

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_result in getUsers.php on line 37 Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in getUsers.php on line 37
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling a member function on a non-object. **It does NOT get any clearer that**. Member function is a function. An object is instance of a class. A non-object is what is not an object. Line 37 says you call `free()` on `$mysqli_result`. You're not required to have a PhD in IT to find out that `$mysqli_result` *is not an object*. Now as for why it's not an object - maybe because it's not mentioned anywhere in the code you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you getting $mysqli_result from? You can only call methods on actual objects.

I assume, `$mysqli_result->free();` should instead be `$result->free();`